# FileNotFoundException but file exists C#

Tags: c#, backup

```
namespace Backup

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Backup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DirectoryInfo> SourceDir = this.lbox_Sources.Items.Cast<DirectoryInfo>().ToList();
        string TargetDir = this.tbox_Target.Text;

        foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in SourceDir)
        {
            foreach (var file in directory.GetFiles())
                File.Copy(file.Name, Path.Combine(TargetDir, file.Name), true);
        }
    }
```

When I try to backup it throws an exception but the file exists and is accessible. Not that good in programming so there is probably some stupid mistake :P

Comment: is the file in use at the time of trying to back up?

Comment: also what is the exact exception that youre seeing

Comment: use `File.Exist()` and `Breakpoints`. Also store `Path.Combine(TargetDir, file.Name)` in a string variable for better debugging.

Comment: Try File.Exists(path) to check wether the file exists and provide the result. Otherwise you could try wether it works with the path directly in code (not through the input box).

Comment: what is the content of `this.lbox_Sources.Items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to modify `File.Copy` line:

```
var targetPath = Path.Combine(TargetDir, file.Name)
File.Copy(file.FullName, targetPath , true);
```

I changed first argument from `file.Name` to `file.FullName` - this should fix the exception

Comment: @LeiYang  `foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in SourceDir)`

Comment: then why not use `file.FullName`

Comment: @LeiYang I agree, `file.FullName` is better here

Answer (score 0):

replace file.Name with file.FullName in File.Copy

```
foreach (var file in directory.GetFiles())
                File.Copy(file.FullName, Path.Combine(TargetDir, file.Name), true);
```